# Signal that a network call inside a for-loop is done, then move onto the next item in the for loop?

Tags: ios, swift

How would I tell the for-loop to move on to the next item in the array in Swift?

```
for (key, value) in commentIds {

    NetworkHelper.makeNetworkCall(key, completionHandler:{
       //Tell current thread the for-loop is being called, to move on to the next item in the for loop?
    }

}
```

I'm planning on having the for-loop in a dispatch_async thread, so it doesn't block the main thread..  Am I designing this wrong..?  Should I have a flag?

*edit*

Flags in the main thread seem to work.   Once the network call is done, flip the flag.

Comment: dispatch your network calls on a serial queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the assumption that if the `makeNetworkCall` method takes a `completionHandler` parameter that it will be doing its work asynchronously.  Given that, the `for` loop will call `makeNetworkCall` for every `key` in `commentIds` before any of them complete.

If you want to process them in series and not start the next one until the prior has finished, you will need to create an array of the keys and write some code like this:

```
var commentIdKeys: Array<KeyType>()?
var keyIndex: Int?

func startRequests() {
    commentIdKeys = Array(commentIds.keys)
    keyIndex = 0

    processNextKey()
}

func processNextKey() {
    guard let keys = commentIdKeys, let index = keyIndex else {
        print("processNextKey() invoked without values set")

        return
    }

    guard keyIndex < keys.count else {
        commentIdKeys = nil
        keyIndex = nil
        print("Finished processing keys")

        return
    }

    NetworkHelper.makeNetworkCall(key, completionHandler:{
        // Do some work

        self.keyIndex = ++index
        self.processNextKey()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Charles, the issue I was running into was it spamming the nginx server.  So I added a sleep to the appropriate thread, then made use of flags in the main thread so it wasn't going to make another network call until the completion callback was triggered.

Comment: The solution I post above wouldn't involve putting threads to sleep, which might be desirable.  It also wouldn't spam the server as each request would have to complete for a subsequent request to start.

Comment: Either way, what you are looking to do is queue up a bunch of network calls to be executed serially. A loop is not an ideal tool. You can create your own queue as @CharlesA. suggests or you can use another tool like a GCD dispatch queue, NSOperation, or my favorite, Bolts https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS